# Import function for class-wide docstring tests

Tags: python, documentation

I am developing on a larger project which has a class with docstrings tests for each method. Each docstring contains a few examples/tests. The docstrings make use of a function in another module frequently and I would like to import it once and have it available in every docstring function test.

For example, if this is `tests.py`

```
class A(object):
    def test1(self):
        """
        >>> myfunc()
        1
        """
        pass
    def test2(self):
        """
        >>> myfunc()
        1
        """
        pass
```

And this is `funcs.py`

```
from tests import A

# Do stuff with A

def myfunc():
    return 1
```

I would like avoid modifying the above code to this:

```
class A(object):
    def test1(self):
        """
        >>> from funcs import myfunc
        >>> myfunc()
        1
        """
        pass
    def test2(self):
        """
        >>> from funcs import myfunc
        >>> myfunc()
        1
        """
    pass
```

And instead do something like a class level docstring module import. I also can't just import the function directly in the module because in my case that would create a circular dependency.

Doctests are invoked using `python -m doctest tests.py` which has this error output:

---

```
File "tests.py", line 4, in tests.A.test
Failed example:
    myfunc()
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1315, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "<doctest tests.A.test[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        myfunc()
    NameError: name 'myfunc' is not defined
********************************************
1 items had failures:
1 of   1 in tests.A.test
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

It succeeds using the test code that has imports.

For anyone wondering why I might want to do this, my real world code is at https://github.com/EntilZha/ScalaFunctional/blob/master/functional/pipeline.py. The function I want to import is `seq` since it is an entrypoint alias to the class `Sequence`. I would prefer to use `seq` in the docstrings since very importantly they serve as documentation examples, `seq` has additional behavior, and I want to start running them as my test suite to make sure they stay up to date.

Comment: You call `myfunc()`, but you define `myfunc(x)`. Are you being subtle, or is that a typo?

Comment: How are you invoking doctest?

Comment: Updated the question to include that and its output. It is run using `python -m doctest tests.py`

Answer (score 0):

From the [`doctest` man page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#what-s-the-execution-context), "*By default, each time doctest finds a docstring to test, it uses a shallow copy of M‘s globals*".

All you have to do is make sure that `myfunc` is present in the module's globals, perhaps by adding

```
from funcs import myfunc
```

to the top of the file.

Comment: The odd issue in my specific case is that this would create a recursive dependency. I will update the example to show that